# Recognition of key data from OCR images

Tags: neural-network, ocr

Is there anyone who are aware of any product, library or solution commercial or open source or even approach which could assist in the following;

I am using Nuance's Omnipage for OCR processing. That works well. But I would like to find data in various forms based on various patterns. This could be vouchers for accounting but the point is that even though the type of raw data is heterogeneous and there are common factors but they are hard to define in rule based ways. 
I found one earlier question which addressed my question partially (but it assumed that I had structured PDF's, which I don't)

There are a few common factors
* The type of documents are similar
* There will be key words either prefixing or above the stuff I am looking for, but those keywords may have synonyms
* There are data like dates which may be in different formats based on the country; e.g. DD/MM/YYYY, MM/DD/YYYY, YYYY-MM-DD, DD'th MMM, YYYY etc. (I assume we would know the country)
* Amounts may be written with decimal point or decimal comma (I assume we would know the country)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you need to build Data Capture solution for semi-structured forms: they all contain basically same set of data, but layout may vary depending on where document come from. There is no silver bullet and you will need to define some rules how to find right field on the documents and what are keywords with their possible synonims, what is the geometrical relationship between keyword and data itself.

However, there is a product that can make this process much easier, and istead of programing that in C++ you will need to describe that relations in visual tool that is specially designed for that and has lot of things already built-in.

[ABBYY FlexiCapture](http://www.abbyy.com/data_capture_software/)

This product is quite powerful and streamiles development of document layout desciptions, its testing and data extraction itself.

There is also an SDK version of it:

[ABBYY FlexiCapture Engine](http://www.abbyy.com/flexicapture_engine/)

Disclaimer: I work for ABBYY

Comment: Is this server based? I don't want to have to process every individual case but want to "teach" the system how to recognise since the same type of documents will frequently be used.

Comment: That is exaclty what it is for: you teach it for typical layouts, and then it works on those layouts automatically. It is not completely magical - once you encounter some new layout you still have to tech it, but that is inevitable in any case. And it has server version too.